# Expandable listview not scrolling inside relatvive layout

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

in my page i have a searchView on the top below that there is a viewPager to show images and an expandablelistview. i need to scroll up the entire view to the top when the listview expands,How can i achieve this, please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Scrollview 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize">

             <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                    android:layout_width="401dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded"
                    android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:queryHint="Search" />


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/Constraint1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandible_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:layout_below="@id/Constraint2"
                android:childDivider="#00000000"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </Scrollview>
```

Comment: Either remove the parent `ScrollView`, or replacing it with `NestedScrollView` and disable nested scrolling on the `ListView`.

Comment: sorry, its not working for me

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` with using `android:fillViewPort="true"` and change relative layout height from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this in your code

```
mainScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.